# Response cookies are empty in windows phone 7 consuming web services

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cookies

I have a windows phone 7 application which consumes web services. In login service it returns a is session id which is based on .NET form authentication, which uses a session cookie.

but in my windows phone 7 application response cookies are empty so i am not able to maintain session in my application.

Here is my code which sends post request to login service

```
        var serviceUrl = new Uri("https://www.bypost.com/api/login");
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        #region

        var container = new CookieContainer();
        container.Add(serviceUrl, new Cookie("abc", "xyz"));
        webRequest.CookieContainer = container;

        #endregion

        webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);
        Console.Write("data sent");
```

and here is my response code:
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                HttpWebResponse response;

```
            response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

            foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cook);
            }
```

but my response.Cookies return null.

Answer (score 0):

The method you have used seems to be correct, but still try copying the **response.cookies** to a **CookieCollection** and then access it.
i.e just change the code as,

```
response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
cookies = response.Cookies;
foreach (Cookie cook in cookies)
{
  Console.WriteLine(cook.Value);
}
```

Still if you didn't get the right answer probably your response does not contain any cookies in it!

Comment: thanks for your reply...the webservices i use, supports HttpOnly and in that we are not able to see cookies